# How to access a sub module register from TestHarness?

Tags: riscv, chisel, rocket-chip

I want to change value stored in a rocket core register from the test bench TestHarness.scala.  How can I access the register?

In `TestHarness.scala`, I think `dut` is used to instantiate the `ExampleRocketSystem` module:

```scala
val dut = Module(LazyModule(new ExampleRocketSystem).module)
```

From the generated Verilog, I see the hierarchy is:

```
ExampleRocketSystem dut
  --RocketTile tile
    --Rocket core
      --target_register
```

So I tried using `dut.tile.core.target_register` to modify the register, however got an error:

> value tile is not a member of freechips.rocketchip.system.ExampleRocketSystemModuleImp[freechips.rocketchip.system.ExampleRocketSystem]